# Ember - Disable Prototype extension

Tags: ember.js

Can anybody check the below link and help me to understand and resolve it.
https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/disable-prototype-extension/16354

Comment: Which environment you want to access that variable? Does that variable is accessible to any environment?\

Comment: Which ember-cli version you are currently using now?

Comment: @Mikelemuel I don't want to override the Native Array prototype behavior in any environment (development/production.) am using 3.0.0 ember cli version.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your EXTEND_PROTOTYPES flag into EmberENV.

```
ENV = {
  ...
  EmberENV: {
    EXTEND_PROTOTYPES: false
  }
  ...
}
```

Check out [ember-guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/#toc_arrays)

Comment: Hi @wuarmin, I tried that and in the above given (ember discussions) link, I have posted that, If I split the ember into another file instead of bundling into vendor.js in ember-cli-build.js am not getting the desired result.

Comment: Hello, why are you splitting it?

Comment: Hello @wuarmin, We will be updating our production servers frequently. If the ember is bundled within the vendor.js file. For every update, vendor.js will be downloaded. To avoid it, we have splitted the ember code in to another file.

Comment: Ok, Check your vendor.js file in browser. The used EmberEnv should be visible